# Why is there a difference between those two JSP files?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have the following JSP.

```
 <s:form id="cursorWait" theme="vs" action="list" method="get" acceptcharset="utf-8">
    <div class="chckbox">
        <s:checkbox id="as" name="as" />
        &nbsp;
        <quartzi:text name="ts" />
    </div>
    <div class="chckbox">
        <s:checkbox id="aec" name="aec" />
        &nbsp;
        <quartzi:text name="tec" /> 
    </div>
    <div class="chckbox">
        <s:checkbox id="aua" name="aua" />
        &nbsp;
        <quartzi:text name="tua" />
        <br/>
        <br/>
    </div>

    <s:select name="seekRA" list="listeChoixRA" value="%{seekRA}" emptyOption="true"/>
    <s:textfield id="numAff" name="seekCode" key="numeroaffaire" />
    <s:textfield id="libAff" name="seekLibelleText" key="libelle" />
    <s:a href="#" cssClass="action_effacer_sans_label" title="%{getText('effacer')}" onClick="gomme()"></s:a>   
    <s:hidden name="firstSearch" value="done" />
    <s:submit id="recherche" key="rechercher" cssClass="wait"/>

</s:form>
<jsp:include page="inc_complex_search.jsp"/>
```

The three div checkbox are redundant to other files, so I decided to put them in a JSP file that I include. My page becomes:

```
<s:form id="cursorWait" theme="vs" action="list" method="get" acceptcharset="utf-8">

<jsp:include page="inc_checkbox_entity.jsp"/>

<s:select name="seekRA" list="listeChoixRA" value="%{seekRA}" emptyOption="true"/>
<s:textfield id="numAff" name="seekCode" key="numeroaffaire" />
<s:textfield id="libAff" name="seekLibelleText" key="libelle" />
<s:a href="#" cssClass="action_effacer_sans_label" title="%{getText('effacer')}" onClick="gomme()"></s:a>   
<s:hidden name="firstSearch" value="done" />
<s:submit id="recherche" key="rechercher" cssClass="wait"/>

</s:form>
<jsp:include page="inc_complex_search.jsp"/>
```

with `inc_checkbox_entity.jsp` being:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="q" uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/q.tld"%>

<div class="chckbox">
    <s:checkbox id="as" name="as" />
    &nbsp;
    <q:text name="toutessocietes" />
</div>
<div class="chckbox">
    <s:checkbox id="aec" name="aec" />
    &nbsp;
    <quartzi:text name="tec" />
</div>
<div class="chckbox">
    <s:checkbox id="aua" name="aua" />
    &nbsp;
    <quartzi:text name="tua" />
</div>
```

And the result is... different...
and I don't understand why.
Shouldn't those two pieces of code produce the same exact page? What makes them different?

Here is a screenshot:
[image: The broken screen]

If I have the code in the main JSP, rather than using an include, then the search entities are under the block "société .. Unités analytiques" and aligned with it.

PS:
I have tried to use

```
<c:import url="inc_checkbox_entity.jsp"/>
but in this case the part between:
    <s:select...
and <s:submit...
```

doesn't appear anymore.

Comment: You failed to mention in what way the result is different.  Do you mean that everything after `<jsp:include page="inc_checkbox_entity.jsp"/>` fails to be rendered? Does that include the content of `<jsp:include page="inc_complex_search.jsp"/>`? Did you check generated HTML or just the screen?

Comment: @GermannArlington Yes sorry, what is happenning is that when I use: <jsp:include page="inc_checkbox_entity.jsp"/> , then the rest of the code (from <s:select name="seekRA" till the end) is rendered but not aligned with the rest. I checked the screen, not the HTML code.

Comment: In that case it is not really Java related question at all. `div`s behave differently if there are any spaces inserted between them, you shoud take a look at generated HTML and see what is different there. Rendering behaviour is fairly complex so you have to make sure that you generate clean and valid HTML

Answer (score 0):

If you use `<jsp:include>` there should be a jsp fragment to be included. But your custom tags didn't like to be included. Thus you might want to modify a jsp fragment so you can use `<jsp:include>` tag.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="q" uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/q.tld"%>

<div class="chckbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="as" name="as" value="${as}"/>
    &nbsp;
    <q:text name="toutessocietes" />
</div>
<div class="chckbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="aec" name="aec" value="${aec}"/>
    &nbsp;
    <quartzi:text name="tec" />
</div>
<div class="chckbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="aua" name="aua" value="${aua}"/>
    &nbsp;
    <quartzi:text name="tua" />
</div>
```

Some custom tags might also not work, better remove/replace them with JSP content if possible.

Comment: Do you mean I should remove the taglib declarations from the include?